# Diet/guidelines for fatty liver condition

Tags: diet, healthy-cooking, fatty-liver-disease

I'm looking for anything that has some reasoning/science behind it.

Comment: If this doesn't address your question, please state what further clarification you are looking for.  If it does, please accept the answer to help us improve our ratios.

Answer (score 2):

In essence, the [recommendation](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/liver-disease/nafld-nash/eating-diet-nutrition) is to eat a low fat diet with the goal of losing weight.  In addition, avoid alcohol use, as you should with any liver issue.

There's really no magic to most dieting needs (there are some that require medical intervention, but your health professional should have gone over them).  Rather it's more an equation: [calories in] - [calories used] < 0 leads to weight loss.